# How to resolve "undefined function TYPO3\CMS\Core\Localization\Parser\simplexml_load_string()" in TYPO3 8 CMS

Tags: php, typo3, simplexml, typo3-8.x

Recently I have installed TYPO3 CMS 8 in my local server, after all configuration wizard finally I got error like "Call to undefined function `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Localization\Parser\simplexml_load_string()`".

Can anyone help me for resolving this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is `php extension` error. install `php7.0-xml` using below command and after restart your apache server.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in german: https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/214932/-typo3-german-gel-st-simplexml-problem-typo3-7-6-und-php-7-auf-ubuntu-server-16-04

> SimpleXML is not active by default in PHP 7 on Ubuntu. See
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593521/php-7-simplexml. After
>   activate them all works.