# Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, ubuntu, simplexml

I have php 7.0 running on my ubuntu server.

php -m command says:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib
```

But still when I run my website, its log says "**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file()**"

Comment: The PHP configuration used on the command-line is not necessarily the same one used when running the website. Try `phpinfo()` on a web page, or check your hosting configuration, to figure out what modules are loaded in that environment.

Comment: Simplexml is not loaded when checked using phpinfo(). But I tried enabling simplexml by command php a2enmod simplexml, still it does not gets enabled. The command does not gives error. Some site says restart /opt/php 7.0-fpm.. But the file is missing.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 54):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by installing `php7.2-xml`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

After that, SimpleXML got listed by `php -m`:

```
$ php -m | grep -i simple
SimpleXML
```

Comment: Likewise, in CentOS 8, I solved it with "yum install php-xml"

Comment: Worked on Debian 10.

Comment: Worked for me too (but php7.3-xml), on Debian 9.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml" then "sudo systemctl reload apache2"  on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thanks! Better add reload apache2 part into the answer.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 I installed `php-xml` using `sudo apt-get install php-xml` and it worked!

Comment: i got error: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of FreePBX\Database::query() must be compatible with PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs): PDOStatement|false in /root/asterisk-20.7.0/freepbx/amp_conf/htdocs/admin/libraries/BMO/Database.class.php on line 240

Answer (score 3):

I'm using ubuntu 18.04. When I checked for SimpleXML in module list, it was stated same like yours.

Then I check my phpinfo() which says it was pulling from different php version and not the same with php cli.

To check php cli version, I run php -v
[image]

To check for phpinfo(), I put the function at the top of index.php of my script.
[image]

After confirming that my phpcli version is different than whats in phpinfo,

I simply run this 2 command

> sudo a2dismod php7.0
>
> sudo a2enmod php7.3

Then restart my apache

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

After that, I test again my phpinfo()

Now it is working.

[image]