# SimpleXML extension must be enabled in php.ini - For Wordpress Slider to work. Ideas?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I realize that this may be easy for some coders. But I'm new to this. I just learned how to import my html template into wordpress creating a custom template. I'm trying to get it to look good, and I wanted a slider to go with it. Every slider I install from wordpress doesn't slide. It just shows the first image and never moves. I installed the "smart slider" and received this error message:

"SimpleXML extension must be enabled in php.ini. Contact your administrator to enable this."

Can someone help provide some insight to this? This may also resolve the issue why other slider plugins aren't working with my custom template. Let me know if you need a copy of CSS or PHP files.

Comment: Is this a VPS, where you can ssh and install stuff? Then, for example, these are instructions for Ubuntu and a few others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593521/php-7-simplexml - but I guess it is not a VPS, then... you can only do exactly what the message suggest, i.e. "Contact your administrator to enable this". Because it's not a matter of your PHP code, or CSS, but a PHP *extension* which apparently is not installed / active.

Comment: Nope, not at all... just trying to add a simple slider to wordpress custom template.

Comment: Where can I go to install it? Ideas?

Comment: Thing is, that if you don't know that, then probably you just can't. My guess is it's some shared hosting like go mommy or something. I think the best option is to really just contact them (the hosting company). Unless... this is localhost?

Comment: Its local. Im using instantwp to design it on a local machine before launch.

Comment: Quick googling revealed you need to ssh into this instantsomething, and then `sudo apk add php7-simplexml` - I think you also need to restart apache/nginx, but really, this software is so niche, that I believe you're left with trying to google the answer. BTW - Here you have a guide - https://github.com/corvideon/InstantWP/blob/master/core/docs/InstantWP-User-Guide.pdf - good luck!